# User Input String Slicing

Tags: python, python-3.3

Write a program that gets a string containing a person's first, middle, and last names, and then display their first, middle, and last initials. For example, if the user enters John William Smith the program should display J. W. S.

That is the exact instructions and this is what i have so far but it prints them in a list not a string.

```
def main():
my_string = input("Enter in your First, Middle and last name: ")    
word_list = my_string.split()

for ch in word_list:
    print(ch[0] + ".")

main()
```

Current Output:

```
Enter in your First, Middle and last name: Nolan Patrick Archer
N.
P.
A.
>>>
```

I can Convert Python 2 into Python 3 its just the concept I am un-able to grasp

Comment: @TimothyChoi by default, `str.split()` splits on whitespace - while explicitly defining it is fine, it's not necessary

Comment: @MattDMo Just read the docs again. Little bit surprised but okay :)

Comment: `my_string` is a string. When you split the string using `my_string.split()` it will result in a list, from the words separated by white space. `['John', 'William', 'Smith']`. Then when you iterate through this list, `for ch in word_list:
    print(ch[0] + ".")`, it grabs the first letter (`ch[0]`) and prints it with a `.` and a newline. [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) for changes to print in Python 3.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `join` to get a single string with the initials and print that out:

```
print(". ".join(word[0] for word in word_list) + ".")
```

Comment: This exactly. You could also do `print(". ".join(word[0].upper() for word in word_list) + ".")` to make sure if I type "adam duncan smith" it still reads my initials as "A. D. S."

Comment: If you really want to avoid this method for some reason, don't (because it's very readable and pythonic). However, if you MUST, then print() accepts a kwarg `end` that specifies the last character to print. By default this is `\n` but you can set it to be an empty string if you like. `print(ch[0].upper()+".", end='')` would also solve, but looks uglier and is less clear.

Comment: +1 for both suggesting to incorporate `upper` and providing more information about the `end` kwarg.

Comment: I used this method and on the next line after this one i added a break so it only displays once. Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Print your result without newlines between the components:

```
for ch in word_list:
    print(ch[0] + '.', end=' ')
print()
```